# Method being referenced in action function is not being called

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction

Hey I was trying out kendo where I was trying to pass the value of the picklist to my controller. The values of the picklists are being captured but my method in the action function is not being called. Where am I going wrong?

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="picklistFilterControllerKendo">
        <head>
            <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.JQuery}"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
            <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
        </head>

        <label>Stage:</label> 
        <div><select id="Stage"></select></div>

        <label>Type:</label> 
        <div><select id="Type"></select></div>

        <label>Region:</label> 
        <div><select id="Region"></select></div>

        <label>Product Group:</label> 
        <div><select id="ProdGroup"></select></div>

        <label>Year:</label> 
        <div><select id="Year"></select></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#Type").kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "text",
                            dataValueField: "value",
                            dataSource:  {!TypeJSON}
                });
                $("#Stage").kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "text",
                            dataValueField: "value",
                            dataSource: {!stageJSON}
                });
                $("#ProdGroup").kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "text",
                            dataValueField: "value",
                            dataSource: {!prodGroupJSON}
                });
                $("#Region").kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "text",
                            dataValueField: "value",
                            dataSource: {!regionJSON}
                });
                $("#Year").kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "text",
                            dataValueField: "value",
                            dataSource: {!YearJSON}
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script>

            function fetchDetails(){
                var Type = $("#Type").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
                var Stage = $("#Stage").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
                var ProdGroup = $("#ProdGroup").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
                var Region = $("#Region").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
                var Year = $("#Year").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
                alert(Type);
                MyFunc(Type, Stage, ProdGroup, Region, Year);
             } 
        </script>

        <apex:form>
            <apex:actionFunction name="MyFunc" action="{!filter}">
                <apex:param name="Type11" value="" assignTo="{!Type}"/> 
                <apex:param name="Stage11" value="" assignTo="{!Stage}"/> 
                <apex:param name="ProdGroup11" value="" assignTo="{!ProdGroup}"/> 
                <apex:param name="Region11" value="" assignTo="{!Region}"/> 
                <apex:param name="Year11" value="" assignTo="{!Year}"/> 
            </apex:actionFunction>
            <apex:commandButton onclick="fetchDetails()" value="Filter"/>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class picklistFilterControllerKendo{
    public String Stage {get;set;}
    public String Type {get;set;}
    public String ProdGroup {get;set;}
    public String Region {get;set;}
    public String Year {get;set;}
    public List <Test__c> testList {get;set;}
    public List<Wrapper> stageList {get;set;}
    public List<Wrapper> yearList {get;set;}
    public List<Wrapper> regionList {get;set;}
    public List<Wrapper> prodGroupList {get;set;}
    public List<Wrapper> typeList {get;set;}
    public Static string regionJSON {get;set;}
    public Static string yearJSON {get;set;}
    public Static string stageJSON {get;set;}
    public Static string prodGroupJSON {get;set;}
    public Static string typeJSON {get;set;}
    public Static string filterListJSON {get;set;}

    public picklistFilterControllerKendo (){
        list<Wrapper> stageList = new list<Wrapper>();      
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Test__c.Stage__c.getDescribe();    
        List<Schema.picklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();    
        stageList.add(new Wrapper('NONE','NONE')); 
        for(Schema.picklistEntry pro:ple)    
        {   
           stageList.add(new Wrapper(pro.getLabel(),pro.getValue()));  
        }
           stageJSON =  JSON.serializePretty(stageList);
           system.debug('********Stage JSON*****'+stageJSON);

        list<Wrapper> yearList = new list<Wrapper>();      
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult1 = Test__c.Year__c.getDescribe();    
        List<Schema.picklistEntry> ple1 = fieldResult1.getPicklistValues();    
        yearList.add(new Wrapper('NONE','NONE')); 
        for(Schema.picklistEntry pro:ple1)    
        {   
           yearList.add(new Wrapper(pro.getLabel(),pro.getValue()));  
        }
           yearJSON =  JSON.serializePretty(yearList);
           system.debug('********Year JSON*****'+yearJSON);

        list<Wrapper> regionList = new list<Wrapper>();      
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult2 = Test__c.Region__c.getDescribe();    
        List<Schema.picklistEntry> ple2 = fieldResult2.getPicklistValues();    
        regionList.add(new Wrapper('NONE','NONE')); 
        for(Schema.picklistEntry pro:ple2)    
        {   
           regionList.add(new Wrapper(pro.getLabel(),pro.getValue()));  
        }
           regionJSON =  JSON.serializePretty(regionList);
           system.debug('********Region JSON*****'+regionJSON);

        list<Wrapper> prodGroupList = new list<Wrapper>();      
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult3 = Test__c.Prod_Group_1__c.getDescribe();    
        List<Schema.picklistEntry> ple3 = fieldResult3.getPicklistValues();    
        prodGroupList.add(new Wrapper('NONE','NONE')); 
        for(Schema.picklistEntry pro:ple3)    
        {   
           prodGroupList.add(new Wrapper(pro.getLabel(),pro.getValue()));  
        }
           prodGroupJSON =  JSON.serializePretty(prodGroupList);
           system.debug('********prodGroupJSON*****'+prodGroupJSON);

        list<Wrapper> typeList = new list<Wrapper>();      
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult4 = Test__c.Type__c.getDescribe();    
        List<Schema.picklistEntry> ple4 = fieldResult4.getPicklistValues();    
        typeList.add(new Wrapper('NONE','NONE')); 
        for(Schema.picklistEntry pro:ple4)    
        {   
           typeList.add(new Wrapper(pro.getLabel(),pro.getValue()));  
        }
           typeJSON =  JSON.serializePretty(typeList);
           system.debug('********Type JSON*****'+typeJSON);
    }

    public void filter () {
        system.debug('************INSIDE FUNCTION**********');
        string query;
        string outerquery = 'Select Name from Test__c WHERE Stage__c ='+'\''+Stage+'\'';

        if(Type != NULL){
            outerquery+='AND Type__c ='+'\''+Type+'\'';
        }
        if(ProdGroup != NULL){
            outerquery+='AND Prod_Group_1__c = '+'\''+ProdGroup+'\'';
        }
        if(Region != NULL) {
            outerquery += 'AND Region__c ='+'\''+Region+'\'';
        }
        if(Year != NULL) {
            outerquery += 'AND Year__c ='+'\''+Year+'\'';
        }


        testList = database.query(+outerquery);
        filterListJSON = JSON.serialize (testList);
        if(filterListJSON == NULL){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'No records found!'));
        }
        system.debug('**********LIST!!************'+filterListJSON );


    }

    public class Wrapper{ 
        public String text{get;set;}
        public String value{get;set;}
        public Wrapper(string text, string value){
            this.text = text;
            this.value = value;
        }
     }
}
```

The function 'Filter' is not being called when I'm clicking the command button.

Comment: try .. in your actionfunction  use rerender attribute `<apex:actionFunction name="MyFunc" action="{!filter}" rerender="frmId">`

Comment: I see you have used {!variableName} syntax when initializing the kendoDropDownList for typeJSON, stageJSON, etc. Here you would need to put it inside single quotes: '{!variableName}'. This will return a string, so you may need to again convert it into JSON in Javascript only.

Comment: @azniq, as I said, the picklist was being displayed and the value selected was captured but my function in the action function wasn't being called. Ratan's approach worked